# Getting error in deleting many documents with $in using mongoose node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to delete records based on incoming(from client side) `array` of `_ids`. My delete function is like this

```
export function removeReferral(ids) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ReferralLink.findByIdAndRemove({ _id: { $in: (ids).map(mongoose.Types.ObjectId) } }, (err, link) => {
        console.log('delete referrals response : ', link)
        if (!err) {
            resolve({
                success: true,
                message: "Referral removed successfully",
                data: null
            });
        } else {

            resolve({
                success: false,
                message: "Unable to remove referral",
                data: err
            });
        }
      });
   });
}
```

But i am getting error like this

```
message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: { '$in': [ 5e1f2e54d4252144ec17501a ] } }" at 
path "_id" for model "referralLinks""
name: "CastError"
stringValue: ""{ _id: { '$in': [ 5e1f2e54d4252144ec17501a ] } }""
kind: "ObjectId"
```

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in general mongoose `findById*'s` would accept a single `_id` as filter, if you pass a string internally mongoose converts string to `_id`, So you cannot pass in an array to it - if want to work with `findByIdAndRemove` - you need to loop on `_id`'s and make multiple DB calls (deleting each document), Also I've changed your code a bit, why to check `!err` ? rather you can check `if(err)` at first then a check to write result. Try this :

Try this :

```
export function removeReferral(ids) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ReferralLink.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: (ids).map(mongoose.Types.ObjectId) } }, (err, link) => {
            console.log('delete referrals response : ', link)
            if (err) {
                resolve({
                    success: false,
                    message: "Unable to remove referral",
                    data: err
                });
            } else if (link.n > 0) { /** Checking if atleast one _id in input array is removed,
                                     Or if you need to check all are deleted then n == array.length */
                resolve({
                    success: true,
                    message: "Referral removed successfully",
                    data: null
                });
            } else {
                resolve({
                    success: true,
                    message: "Not able to remove Referrals successfully",
                    data: null
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```